# fatal error: gnu/stubs-soft.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, makefile, cross-compiling

I had the below error while cross compiling a helloworld program on 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04, for 32 bit Cortex A9 platform.

```
$ make
/usr/local/comp/poky/1.7/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/usr/local/comp/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi -Iinclude -Wall -O3 -c -o main.o main.c
In file included from /usr/local/comp/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/features.h:389:0,
             from /usr/local/comp/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/stdio.h:27,
             from main.c:5:
/usr/local/comp/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:29: fatal error: gnu/stubs-soft.h: No such file or directory
# include <gnu/stubs-soft.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
makefile:45: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Then I examine the content of the stubs.h file:

```
$ cat /usr/local/comp/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h 
/* This file is automatically generated.
   This file selects the right generated file of `__stub_FUNCTION' macros
   based on the architecture being compiled for.  */


#if !defined __ARM_PCS_VFP
# include <gnu/stubs-soft.h>
#endif
#if defined __ARM_PCS_VFP
# include <gnu/stubs-hard.h>
#endif
```

Shall I define the `_ARM_PCS_VFP` in the makefile?

Comment: Is this Yocto?  Have you sourced the environment file provided with the SDK (probably `/usr/local/comp/poky/1.7/environment-something` (use tab completion)?

Comment: Thanks Steve, `$ source /usr/local/comp/poky/1.7/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi` works. I can see the `-mfloat-abi=hard` is enabled inside that file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the name of your cross compiler, "cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi", it targets the Cortex-A9 with VFP architecture and neon enabled. Adding `-mfloat-abi=hard` switch should solve the problem.

> From GCC manual:
>
> -mfloat-abi=name:
>
> Specifies which floating-point ABI to use. Permissible values are:
> ‘soft’, ‘softfp’ and ‘hard’.
>
> Specifying ‘soft’ causes GCC to generate output containing library
> calls for floating-point operations. ‘softfp’ allows the generation of
> code using hardware floating-point instructions, but still uses the
> soft-float calling conventions. ‘hard’ allows generation of
> floating-point instructions and uses FPU-specific calling conventions.
>
> The default depends on the specific target configuration. Note that
> the hard-float and soft-float ABIs are not link-compatible; you must
> compile your entire program with the same ABI, and link with a
> compatible set of libraries.

Comment: I am new to this cross compiler stuff, where do I place the -m in an eclipse setting?

Answer (score 1):

To define, which package is missing, run the command

```
sudo apt-file search stubs-soft.h
```

It shows that package `libc6-dev-armel-cross` contains the file `stubs-soft.h`
So, install missing package by command

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-armel-cross
```

It will provide the file `stubs-soft.h` for the local machine