# gnu/stubs-soft.h no such file or directory when build qml for yocto

Tags: linux, qml, embedded-linux, yocto, beagleboneblack

I'm following this tutorial https://www.ics.com/blog/configuring-qt-creator-yocto-development for deploy qml application for yocto on beaglebone black. But I had an error "gnu/stubs-soft.h no such file or directory" . I can deploy qt console, qt widget but i can't deploy qml  to yocto. Does someone have a solution for this? or Does someone have a solution for deploy qml to yocto? . Sorry my english is not good.  Thanks you for reading!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: gnu/stubs-soft.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139125/fatal-error-gnu-stubs-soft-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Hi  Oleksandr Kravchuk . Yes i saw that , but i don't understand that solution . what dose " Adding -mfloat-abi=hard switch should solve the problem " this mean??

Comment: compile your program with those flags

Comment: Hi Oleksandr Kravchuk. Can you guide step by step for me?? I don't understand. Where do I add it??