# Boost cross compilation with custom Yocto SDK fails with "No such file or directory" errors

Tags: c++, boost, cross-compiling, yocto

I've been given a custom Yocto SDK so as to build a c++ app I've created and the third party libraries that the app depends on.
I've installed the SDK on a VM Ubuntu 16.04.
The first library I needed to build was boost. I use  version. 1.64.
I follow the same steps I follow each time to build boost either on a Yocto SDK or a default arm compiler.

```
$ . /opt/environment-setup-poky-linux-gnueabi
$ ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem,iostreams,program_options,regex,system --prefix=/home/user/Libs
$ nano ~/user-config.jam  where I place the following commands
$ using gcc : arm : /opt/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ --sysroot= /opt/sysroots/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi ;                      
$ ./b2 install toolset=gcc-arm  link=shared threading=multi
```

However I always get the following error :

```
    gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/error_code.o
In file included from /opt/sysroots/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:55,
                 from /opt/sysroots/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/features.h:452,
                 from /opt/sysroots/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/8.2.0/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /opt/sysroots/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/8.2.0/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/bits/c++config.h:508,
                 from /opt/sysroots/amr-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/8.2.0/cstddef:49,
                 from ./boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:165,
                 from ./boost/config.hpp:39,
                 from ./boost/system/config.hpp:13,
                 from ./boost/system/error_code.hpp:14,
                 from libs/system/src/error_code.cpp:16:
/opt/sysroots/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h:7:11: fatal error: gnu/stubs-soft.h: No such file or directory
 # include <gnu/stubs-soft.h>
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I assume that the sysroot is not found correctly.

When I tried with a user-config.jam that does not contain --sysroot variable I get the error :

```
 gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/threading-multi/error_code.o
In file included from ./boost/config.hpp:39,
                 from ./boost/system/config.hpp:13,
                 from ./boost/system/error_code.hpp:14,
                 from libs/system/src/error_code.cpp:16:
./boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:165:10: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory
 #include <cstddef>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The CC variable on the environment setup contains the follwoing:

```
export CC="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7ve  -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
```

Is there something I can do to bypass these errors or the SDK is faulty and needs rebuilt ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139125/fatal-error-gnu-stubs-soft-h-no-such-file-or-directory  looks like it's conditionally included and you need to setup/change some #defines or compiler switches

Comment: @RichardCritten  I've seen the post.  The solution is to include flag -mfloat-abi=hard. However as I mention on the post on the environment setup file CC includes this flag. So it seems that building somehow bypasses the environment variables and I haven't found why.

Comment: Hi dk13, unfortunately I don't know the boost build system goood enough, but judging on current recipes for boost1.75 (https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/recipes-support/boost/boost.inc) you need to manually provide some additional flags (BJAM_OPTS_append_arm = " abi=aapcs architecture=arm") for example. I'd suggest you take a look at those recipes to get inspired on how to build boost or if this is an option, use existing recipes.